# MySql: Limit the times a user appears in the results of select query

Tags: mysql

I'm lost here :)

I need to limit the number of times a user appears in the results of a select query.

Let's consider this two tables:

```
user
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id    | firstname | lastname |    max_articles     |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| u01        | Yusuf     | Shakeel  |         2           |
| u02        | John      | Doe      |         6           |
| u03        | Jane      | Doe      |         4           |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------------------+

articles
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| article_id | user_id   | content   |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| art01      | u01       | BláBláBlá |
| art02      | u01       | BláBláBlá |
| art03      | u03       | BláBláBlá |
| art04      | u03       | BláBláBlá |
| art05      | u02       | BláBláBlá |
| art06      | u01       | BláBláBlá |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

In user table there is the max articles that can appear for each user.

So when i do:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
```

It will list all articles. As you can see user u01 has 3 articles, but it just can appear 2 articles based on user table info.

What i need is to select all articles but limit the number of articles for each user depending on user.max_articles

Is this possible? How can i solve this?

I hope I have been able to explain what I mean.
I am using MySql.

Thank you all very much.

P.S. - I edited almost everything. Thank you.

EDIT

The select query should consider the two tables. Something like this:

```
SELECT articles.* FROM articles
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = articles.user_id
```

So some how it should count the results that are being listed for each user and compare it with user.max_articles If it is >= it keeps listing results except from that user - it should do this for each user while listing.

How can this be done?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, could you please show a bit of your table and data any MySQL query that you've already tested (if any)? Also, it is better if you can illustrate how your expected output it would be. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group you may be able to find some ideas there.

Comment: @tcadidot0 thank you for your comment. I edited the question. Please see if it is better explained.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @PeterPan. May I know, do you want the max value from `article_id` for each user (for example `u01=art06`) or the total of how many occurrences there is for each user (for example `u01= 3 times`)?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I edited again, please take a look and perhaps is the best way to answer your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if the result is anywhere close to what you're trying to achieve:

```
SELECT articles.user_id,
       -- 1st operation 
       COUNT(ARTICLE_ID) AS op1, 
       -- 2nd operation
       MAX(ARTICLE_ID) AS op2, 
       -- 3rd operation
       IF(COUNT(ARTICLE_ID) >= MAX_ARTICLES, COUNT(ARTICLE_ID),'') AS op3, 
       MAX_ARTICLES
          FROM articles 
          LEFT JOIN USER ON user.user_id = articles.user_id 
 GROUP BY USER.USER_ID;
```

Comment: thank you for answer. But in a glance i think it wont work because i need the a list of articles and your query is grouping by user :/

Comment: If like that, please edit your question and include an illustration of how would your expected output look like. You can re-use the `user or articles` table in your question and change the data accordingly. That way we can determine which is the bast practice to get your desired result. ;)